# Two continuous functions $f,g$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$ generate a uniformly continuous function

Tags: calculus

Assume that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous function and $g:[b,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous function and $f(b)=g(b).$ I have to prove that the function

$h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)\text{ if } a\le x \le b\\ g(x)\text{ if } x \ge b \end{cases}$

is a uniformly continuous function. Honestly I have been trying to solve this one for some time. I've tried to use the definition that since $g$ is uniformly continuous then for $\delta >0$ and for all $x,y$ we have $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - g(y)| <\epsilon$ but I can't use this definition to $h$

Comment: Split the cases $x,y > b$ and $x,y < b $and $x>h,y<b$. The first two cases are obvious. For the third case and you could split the target quantity you want to cap in  |g(x)-g(y)| < |g(x)-g(b)| + |g(b)-g(y)|

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,b]$ because it is continuous on a compact set. Hence there is a corresponding $\delta_1$ by definition of uniform continuity which works for $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. $g$ is uniformly continuous in $[b,\infty)$, so there is a corresponding $\delta_2$ which works for $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. We want to prove that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon$. If both points $x,y$ are in $[a,b]$ then it is obviously true, same thing if both points are in $[b,\infty)$. Now assume $x\in [a,b]$ and $y\in (b,\infty)$. Then:

$|h(x)-h(y)|=|h(x)-h(b)+h(b)-h(y)|=|f(x)-f(b)+g(b)-g(y)|\leq$

$\leq |f(x)-f(b)|+|g(b)-g(y)|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

We used the fact that if $|x-y|\leq\delta$ then $|x-b|,|b-y|\leq\delta$ as well, because $b$ is a point between $x$ and $y$.